# Python regex: not more than one special symbol in a row

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a way to get those substrings that had no more than 1 special symbols among [a-z] in a row.
Here is the example:

```
sp_sym = '/,@ '
text1 = 'as for@you' # <- ok
text2 = 'as for@ you ' # <- ok
text3 = 'as for@@you ' # <- not good
```

An expression like `[a-z(?:/,@){1}]` is not working.

Comment: would `as for,@you` be valid or invalid?

Comment: is this `foo*h*` valid or not?

Comment: `for,@you` - valid; `foo*h*` - valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching for strings that do *not* have two characters in a row, why not search for those that *do*? Then, your result is all of the other strings.

```
result = []
for string in (text1, text2, text3):
    if not re.search(r'[/,@]{2,}', string):
        result.append(string)
```

If you prefer a one-liner:

```
result = [s for s in (text1,text2,text3) if not re.search(r'[/,@]{2,}', s)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The below regex won't match the strings if it has consecutive `/` or `,` or `@` symbols inside lowercase letters,

```
^(?:(?!([,\/@])\1+)[a-z\W])+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nR7cO4/5)

Answer (score 1):

Try matching the characters followed by anything that is not one of the characters: `[/,@][^/,@]`.

The brackets are sets that match any characters between them, so `[/,@]` matches / or , or @. But when the first character in the brackets is `^`, this negates the set so it matches everything but the characters in the set.

Edit: of course you have to make sure that there is not one of these characters before the pattern as well. So then it becomes: `[^/,@][/,@][^/,@]`. Now the only problem might be that you cannot match a single special character at the beginning or end of the string. Do you need to match those?